# page scroll up to specific position instead of default scroll stoping point using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am doing some jquery implementation, I am trying to scroll a webpage up to specific position through jquery code, but when I write this code for scrolling

```
$("#portfolio ").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#portfolioto").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

page scroll and stop to some default position, but I want to give a specific position to control the page scrolling according to my given point. So how could I do this, I tried but I am unable to achieve my goal. Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand this : *but i want to give a specific position to control the page scrolling according to my given point* ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes when i scroll for example i click on about me tab on menu then my page scroll down to about me section/div but some part of that about me div hide under the menubar. i dont want that div to be hidden under my menu bar after scrolling